# Python dash - tooltip problem at datatable

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

Below is the code of a datatable from my dash app. It's working fine, but the only problem is, when I use a filter, the tooltip brings data from the table before the filter.

Example:

[image]

When the mouse cursor is over the first line of that column, it prints `Acima de 120 dias` (Over 120 days), the same value of that cell

Example when filtered:

[image]

When the mouse cursor is over the first line of that column, it prints "Acima de 120 dias" (Over 120 days), the value that was originally there before the filter and not "Acima de 90 dias" (Over 90 days).

Please, if needed, I can try to add a piece from the callback that is responsible for this table.

The database comes from an excel file.

Sample in dict:

```
dff={'Primary Value': {0: 250025.0, 1: 25.0, 2: 25.0, 3: 100.0, 4: 100.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}, 'FarolAging': {0: 'vermelho', 1: 'vermelho', 2: 'vermelho', 3: 'vermelho', 4: 'vermelho', 5: 'vermelho', 6: 'vermelho', 7: 'vermelho', 8: 'vermelho', 9: 'vermelho'}, 'Contrato': {0: '703', 1: '106', 2: '101', 3: '101', 4: '1011', 5: '102', 6: '106', 7: '102', 8: '102', 9: '1020'}, 'Dias Pendentes': {0: 'Acima de 120 dias', 1: 'Acima de 120 dias', 2: 'Acima de 120 dias', 3: 'Acima de 120 dias', 4: 'Acima de 120 dias', 5: 'Acima de 120 dias', 6: 'Acima de 120 dias', 7: 'Acima de 120 dias', 8: 'Acima de 120 dias', 9: 'Acima de 120 dias'}, 'Produto': {0: 'Financeiro', 1: 'Financeiro', 2: 'Financeiro', 3: 'Financeiro', 4: 'Financeiro', 5: 'Credito', 6: 'Credito', 7: 'Financeiro', 8: 'Financeiro', 9: 'Credito'}, 'Cliente': {0: 'CAMERA', 1: 'CAMERA', 2: 'CAMERA', 3: 'CAMERA', 4: 'CAMERA', 5: 'SANTOS', 6: 'LBB', 7: 'MAURO', 8: 'MAURO', 9: 'MAURO'}, 'Cliente Grupo': {0: 'DARCI CAMERA', 1: 'CAMERA', 2: 'CAMERA', 3: 'CAMERA', 4: 'CAMERA', 5: 'GENERICO', 6: 'GENERICO', 7: 'GENERICO', 8: 'GENERICO', 9: 'GENERICO'}, 'XXX': {0: 953, 1: 953, 2: 953, 3: 953, 4: 953, 5: 168, 6: 107, 7: 888, 8: 888, 9: 888}, 'Abertura': {0: '25/02/2021', 1: '01/04/2019', 2: '22/10/2019', 3: '23/09/2019', 4: '20/09/2019', 5: '13/06/2022', 6: '12/07/2022', 7: '26/09/2022', 8: '26/09/2022', 9: '26/09/2022'}, 'Tipo': {0: 'Tipo 1 – 4790', 1: 'Tipo 1', 2: 'Tipo 2', 3: 'Tipo 3', 4: 'Tipo 3', 5: 'Tipo 4', 6: 'Tipo 4', 7: 'Tipo 5', 8: 'Tipo 4', 9: 'Tipo 4'}, 'Descrição Garantia': {0: 'Sem Descrição', 1: 'Sem Descrição', 2: 'Sem Descrição', 3: 'Sem Descrição', 4: 'Sem Descrição', 5: 'Sem Descrição', 6: 'Sem Descrição', 7: 'Sem Descrição', 8: 'Sem Descrição', 9: 'Sem Descrição'}, 'Observacao': {0: 'Sem Observação', 1: 'Sem observação', 2: 'Sem observação', 3: 'Sem observação', 4: 'Sem observação', 5: 'Sem Observações', 6: 'Sem observação', 7: 'Sem observação', 8: 'Cobrado', 9: 'Aguardando'}, 'Data de Vencimento': {0: '01/01/9999', 1: '01/04/2020', 2: '30/03/2020', 3: '30/04/2020', 4: '30/04/2020', 5: '11/06/2027', 6: '11/07/2029', 7: '21/09/2023', 8: '27/09/2027', 9: '27/09/2027'}, 'Data': {0: 'unknown', 1: '19/03/2021', 2: '30/03/2020', 3: '15/04/2020', 4: '23/09/2019', 5: 'unknown', 6: 'unknown', 7: 'unknown', 8: 'unknown', 9: 'unknown'}, 'Início': {0: '25/02/2021', 1: '01/04/2019', 2: '22/10/2019', 3: '23/09/2019', 4: '20/09/2019', 5: '13/06/2022', 6: '12/07/2022', 7: '26/09/2022', 8: '26/09/2022', 9: '26/09/2022'}, 'Data Fim': {0: '25/03/2021', 1: '10/04/2019', 2: '26/12/2019', 3: '26/11/2019', 4: '25/11/2019', 5: '16/08/2022', 6: '14/09/2022', 7: '01/12/2022', 8: '01/12/2022', 9: '01/12/2022'}, 'Moeda': {0: 'BRL', 1: 'USD', 2: 'BRL', 3: 'BRL', 4: 'BRL', 5: 'BRL', 6: 'USD', 7: 'BRL', 8: 'BRL', 9: 'BRL'}, 'Valor': {0: '0,00', 1: '4.500', 2: '2.350', 3: '19.450.00', 4: '20.917', 5: '25.000', 6: '500', 7: '12.000', 8: '30.000', 9: '32.340'}, 'Rating': {0: 'B', 1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'F', 4: 'G', 5: 'A', 6: 'B', 7: 'A', 8: 'C', 9: 'A'}, 'Nível': {0: 'A', 1: 'E', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'A', 9: 'A'}, 'Valor2': {0: 'unknown', 1: 'unknown', 2: 'unknown', 3: 'unknown', 4: 'unknown', 5: '12000', 6: '2100', 7: '2030', 8: '2520', 9: '2520'}, 'Caracteristicas': {0: 'Ativas', 1: 'Ativas', 2: 'Ativas', 3: 'Ativas', 4: 'Ativas', 5: 'Ativas', 6: 'Ativas', 7: 'Ativas', 8: 'Ativas', 9: 'Ativas'}, 'Officer': {0: 'SILVA', 1: 'SILVA', 2: 'SILVA', 3: 'SILVA', 4: 'SILVA', 5: 'RENATO', 6: 'JOAO', 7: 'MATHEUS', 8: 'MATHEUS ', 9: 'MATHEUS'}, 'Segmento': {0: 'Clients 01', 1: 'Clients 01', 2: 'Clients 01', 3: 'Clients 01', 4: 'Clients 01', 5: 'Clients 01', 6: 'Clients 01', 7: 'Clients 01', 8: 'Clients 01', 9: 'Clients 01'}, 'Pré/Pós': {0: 'Pré', 1: 'Pré', 2: 'Pré', 3: 'Pré', 4: 'Pré', 5: 'Pré', 6: 'Pré', 7: 'Pré', 8: 'Pré', 9: 'Pré'}, 'Coordenador': {0: 'Coordenação Diversa', 1: 'Coordenação Diversa', 2: 'Coordenação Diversa', 3: 'Coordenação Diversa', 4: 'Coordenação Diversa', 5: 'Coordenação Clientes 01', 6: 'Coordenação Clientes 01', 7: 'Coordenação Clientes 01', 8: 'Coordenação Clientes 01', 9: 'Coordenação Clientes 01'}, 'Analista': {0: 'Analistas Diversos', 1: 'Analistas Diversos', 2: 'Analistas Diversos', 3: 'Analistas Diversos', 4: 'Analistas Diversos', 5: 'Thai', 6: 'Amorim', 7: 'Motta', 8: ' Motta', 9: 'Motta'}}
```

```
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, prevent_initial_callbacks=True)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
 html.Div([
  html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
                id="tablef",
                style_data={
                    'maxWidth': 710,
                    'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',


                },
                style_table={
                    'overflowX': 'scroll',
                    "maegin-top": "15px",
                },
                columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, 'deletable': True} for i in dff.columns],
                data=dff.to_dict('records'),
                filter_action='native',

                style_cell={
                    'textAlign': 'left'
                },


                tooltip_data=[{
                    column: {'value': str(value), 'type': 'markdown'}
                    for column, value in row.items()
                } for row in dff.to_dict('records')],
                tooltip_delay=0,
                tooltip_duration=None,
                page_size=25,
            ),

        ], className='col-md-10'),
    ], className='row')
])
```

Comment: Thanks for including your code – I think in order to reproduce your dash app, we need a small sample of your data so that we know what `dff` looks like. can you include the output from `dff.head(10).to_dict()` in your question?

Comment: Derek, I added at the question a sample that I extracted from `dff.head(10).to dict()`, please, see if it helps

Comment: what is the desired behavior? do you want the table to be empty as you're typing the filter?

Comment: No, the table is working fine, but there's this tool called tooltip, when the mouse coursor is above the cell from the filtered table, it shows the data from the table before the filter, not from the actual filtered table.